# Why My transaction code is not working in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
being try
being transaction 
insert into branch values('Dholanwal','Faisalabad',1200);
insert into account values('l-111','Dholanwal',1200);
commit transaction
end try
being catch
if (@@ERROR >0)

rollback transaction
end catch
```

> Error starting at line : 4 in command -
>   insert into account values('l-111','Dholanwal',1200)
>   Error report -
>   ORA-00001: unique constraint (mehran.SYS_C0012129) violated
>
> Unknown Command: commit transaction
>   end try
>   being catch
>   if (@@ERROR >0)

rollback transaction
end catch

Comment: This looks like SQL Server code, but your error and tag are Oracle.  Very confusing.

Comment: This is obviously not the code you actually ran, because spelling errors in code, such as using `being` insted of `begin`, will not allow execution to even be started. Yet somehow you got a constraint violation error, from Oracle. Are you accessing an Oracle database through some sort of query pass-through mechanism in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

> *Why My transaction code is not working in oracle?*

It does not work because it is T-SQL(Micosoft SQL Server or Sybase).

Oracle syntax:

```
BEGIN
   insert into branch(col1, col2, col3) values('Dholanwal','Faisalabad',1200);
   insert into account(col1, col2, col3) values('l-111','Dholanwal',1200);
   commit;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
END;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40b7752f66eb5bf9521838f1913e365a)**